# ODFDOM Java PDF converter messed up encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding, odf, odfdom

I want to convert an .odt file to .pdf in my web java application. I have an .odt file in Bulgarian (cyrillic) and it converts successfully on my local machine. However, on the cloud server all the cyrillics are skipped and only the latin symbols and numbers remain. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Why don't use ask on ODFDOM why their pre-version 1.0 code from 2011 is flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like server doesn't have some fonts. So, try to install corresponding packages with fonts. For example for Ubuntu this is usually: urw-fonts, ttf-mscorefonts, etc.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, I missed the right type of font. :)